# Assigning a value to a polygon cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, arcgis-10.3, table

In ArcMap 10.3 I have a raster file with a polygon grid overlayed on it:[image]

If the pixels in the colored raster have values such as blue = 5, yellow = 1, green = 3 etc, is there a way to output a table that will show the total number of blue, yellow, and green raster cells within the polygon cell (or something like 20 blue/5 cells so blue cells = 100 and so on) . Something similar to tabulate area would be great except I just need the total number/ total value.

This seems like an odd question to me so feel free to ask for clarification. It is difficult to think of all that I need to explain.

Comment: You can mask the raster to the polygon cell and then run the 'Summary Statistics' tool.  By using the 'count' statistic, you can output a table with what you need.  Python could automate this... but you can also try the 'Zonal Statistics as Table' tool if you have spatial analyst.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Spatial Analyst?

1. Reselect the four polygons into their own feature class.
2. Assign unique IDs to the four polygons.
3. Convert the four polygons to a grid with the same resolution as the data raster.
4. Use the "Tabulate Area" tool in zonal toolset of spatial analyst toolbox. It will calculate total area of each combination of values from the two grids.
5. Use field calculator to divide that by cell area and then multiply by cell value.

Comment: I do have Spatial Analyst. I need to do this for the entire colored raster and polygon grid (the selected four were only for showing someone and forgot to clear the selection). What would be the easiest way of turning the polygon grid into a grid with same resolution as the raster?(polygon to raster for some reason does not work...though that doesn't mean I'm not doing something stupid haha)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until now. But polygon to raster is what I would have suggested. Not sure why it didn't work for you.